# pythonのクラス内クラスについて

Tags: python, python3

動作はしているのですが，メモリを無駄に使用量しているのは明らかですし，他にもっと良い方法があると思うのです．
知識を貸していただけないでしょうか．したいことは
data.generate.mu_sigma()
ようにパラメータを生成したり，変更したりして
data.mu
としてデータの参照することです．

理由は
data.generate＿mu_sigma(self)
というような方法では，予測補間での検索が大変なことや，
data.generate.
data.generate2.
などを作って別な生成方法を試したりしたいからです

.pyファイルでモジュールとしてあつかえばいいかなとも思いましたが，オブジェクトとして値が保持されなかったりするのかなと考えたりしてしまします．

他にもcの構造体のように型をだけを宣言するクラスと，処理を主に扱うクラスをまとめたクラスなどをつくれたら,うれしいなと思うのですが，不可能でしょうか．

よろしくお願いします．

```
import numpy as np
class test_data:
    def __init__(self,n_samples,dim):
        class generate:
            def __init__(self,n_samples,dim):
                self.n_samples = n_samples
                self.dim = dim
                self.mu = 0.0
                self.sigma = 0.0

            def mu_sigma(self):
                self.mu = np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=self.dim)
                self.sigma = np.random.uniform(low=1.0, high=2.0, size=self.dim)

        self.n_samples = n_samples
        self.dim = dim
        self.generate = generate(n_samples,dim)
        self.generate.mu_sigma()
        self.mu = self.generate.mu
        self.sigma = self.generate.sigma

data=test_data(n_samples=10,dim=2)
print(data.generate.mu)
print(data.mu)
```

結果
[ 0.97730724  1.0678634 ]
[ 0.97730724  1.0678634 ]

Answer (score 2):

参考までに、inner class の代わりに named tuple を返す関数を使う方法などを。

```
import collections
import numpy as np

class test_data:
  def __init__(self, n_samples, dim, generator):
    self.n_samples = n_samples
    self.dim = dim
    self.generate = generator(n_samples, dim)
    self.mu = self.generate.mu
    self.sigma = self.generate.sigma

def generator(n_samples, dim):
  generate = collections.namedtuple('generate', ['mu', 'sigma'])
  return generate(
    mu = np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=dim),
    sigma = np.random.uniform(low=1.0, high=2.0, size=dim))

data = test_data(n_samples=10, dim=2, generator=generator)

print(data.generate.mu)
print(data.mu)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます，おもしろかったです．今回僕が提示した条件に対しては，とても良い解決方法だとおもいます．もうひとつできたらうれしいなということがあって，それは```data = test_data(n_samples=10, dim=2, generator=generator)```を generator=generator2としたときに```self.generate = generator(n_samples, dim)```の```generator(n_samples, dim)```の引数やその数をかえられたらというものです．ご存知で気が向いたら回答頂きたいです．

Answer (score 1):

なぜクラス内にクラスを定義したいのかよくわかりません。普通に２つのクラスを定義して、test_dataのクラスから、内部に持つgenerateクラスに処理を委譲すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
import numpy as np

class GenerateData:

    def __init__(self, n_samples, dim):
        self.n_samples = n_samples
        self.dim = dim

    @property
    def mu(self):
        return np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=self.dim)

    @property
    def sigma(self):
        return np.random.uniform(low=-2.0, high=2.0, size=self.dim)

class TestData:

    def __init__(self, n_samples, dim):
        self.generate_data = GenerateData(n_samples, dim)

    @property
    def mu(self):
        return self.generate_data.mu

    @property
    def sigma(self):
        return self.generate_data.sigma

test = TestData(n_samples=10, dim=2)

print(test.mu)
print(test.sigma)
```